# SetOnClickListener on Navigational Drawer Items in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to declare the slider items as a `Button` but it keeps on crashing. I'm trying to access a different `Activity` when an item is pressed, and trying out the Log out button. Here's the xml of the **activity_main_drawer**.

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_home"
        android:title="Home"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_medication"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_medication"
        android:title="Medication" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notices"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_notices"
        android:title="Doctor's Notices" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/meds"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu_buy"
        android:title="Buy Medicines" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/options"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="Medic Options">

        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">


                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_add"
                    android:icon="@drawable/menu_add"
                    android:title="Add Medicines" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_dispense"
                    android:icon="@drawable/menu_dispense"
                    android:title="Dispense" />

            </group>
        </menu>

    </item>

</group>

<item android:title="Settings">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/account"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_account"
            android:title="Account" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/help"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_help"
            android:title="Help" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/bLogout"
            android:icon="@drawable/menu_help"
            android:title="Logout"
            />
    </menu>
</item>
```

**Tried using:**

```
Button bLogout;
bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
bLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
```

But it still crashes.

Comment: the thing is your casting a menu item to a button thats not going to work instead use a OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

Answer (score 0):

Use this `NavigationView` item clicked

```
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id. bLogout:
                        // your logic goes here
                        break;
                }


            }
        });
```